# Thread change variable value and see changes outside it

Tags: c++, multithreading

I created a thread that calls a function to change a variable value, but when it finished the values is not changed anymore.

Its just an example, its not the real code.

```
THREAD1:
 if(size = socket.recv(data))deserializeData(data)

deserializeData(){
 //Deserialize the data (csv format) and then copy to command
 command = tmp;
}

Outside the thread
cout << command
```

Inside the thread and the deserializeData if i call the command it shows correctly, but outside when i do the cout it shows nothing.

I saw about the volatile, but i tried with my string variable and it dont work.

Thanks

Comment: Is there more then one thread that has access to the variable?

Comment: 'not the real code' means you won't be able to get much 'real help'

Comment: How and in what scope is `command` defined? Are you sure the `cout` gets executed after the assignment?

Comment: You need a memory barrier, `volatile` does not help (except with VC++ 2005+).

Comment: Sounds like a classic concurrency problem -- quite possibly, you're trying to print out `command` before the thread has actually finished reading it (but as @SteveTownsend implied, we have no way of knowing based on the little you've posted).

Comment: i print the command inside the thread and outside, the order is correct, but i cant see.

Comment: Its not the real code but its exactly that what happen, the code is big and uses socket so i didn't showed everything. I have a while outside the thread that prints the command, but it dont work. I declare the command in the begin of the code (GLOBAL VARIABLE) outside the int main

Answer (score 0):

If `command` is shared between multiple threads, then you need a CriticalSection (or whatever favorite locking mechanism you like) to guard all read/write access to it.  Otherwise, `cout` might print garbage, nothing at all, format your harddrive, who knows what, since THREAD1 could be writing to `command` at the same time.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if one thread only writes, and other only reads

Comment: @demonofnight So... can one thread write to the same `command` instance while the other thread is reading from it?  If so, then each thread must do something to protect concurrent access to this same object.